# Java socket second write attempt fails

Tags: java, sockets

I have a function:

```
...
socket.getOutputStream().write("something".getBytes());
socket.getOutputStream().flush();
...
```

Works fine. Keep socket open.
Trying to call this function again but get the error: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe

despite the fact that

socket.isClosed - false
socket.isOutputShutdown - false
socket.isConnected - true

Comment: timeout connection are detected only when new data is written...  checking isClosed() _before_ write _do_ _not_ work.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this via local Socket and ServerSocket test. There is something in your particular case, could you please provide more info?

Answer (score 3):

It is most likely the other end has closed the connection. It is possible the first write failed as well, as write() does not guarenteed delivery. You only get an Exception once it knows the other end is not listening.

`isClosed` means; have I closed the connection

`isOutputShutdown` means; have I shutdown the output

`isConnected` means; has it ever connected

The only way to detect that a connection is truly up is to get a response from the other end telling you it has received your data. e.g. a response to a heartbeat.  Without that response (which must be part of your protocol) you cannot be sure the other end has received it.

Answer (score 0):

Broken pipe means that you wrote data to a connection that had already been closed by the other end. This can indicate an application protocol error.